# Presto EMR connect externally with presto driver

Tags: amazon-emr, presto, apache-superset

I wanted to connect my Presto which is running on my AWS EMR cluster. The connection should be presto driver connection as I am using superset which does not accepts JDBC Presto connections.

I tried to connect using the public DNS in superset which didn't work. There are no firewals set for my cluster.

Comment: Can you update your question with superset config used and errors encountered with stack trace ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Im running the superset in local machine using docker. I wanted to connect my presto service using presto driver in superset. I am getting timed out error. 
`superset.exceptions.SupersetTimeoutException: Please check your connection details and database settings, and ensure that your database is accepting connections, then try connecting again.`
Guess my cluster is not accepting http connection even though after modifying the inbound rules of security groups.